# What’s the meaning of revelation 20:6

Tags: revelation, new-testament

The resurrection to heavenly life is called “the first resurrection.” (Revelation 20:6) This indicates that there will be another resurrection. It will be an earthly one.

is that the meaning? I don’t even understand the paragraphs.

Answer (score 1):

#### *What’s the meaning of  Revelation 20:6*

First, Christians are those seated on the thrones. We are given authority to judge the world (1 Cor. 6:3) through our obedience to the Gospel. The “souls under the altar” (Rev. 6:9) are merely the totality of saints that have suffered throughout history for the cause of Christ and the Word of God. Now, we have:

**Revelation 20:6 – Paraphrased**

> “Blessed and holy is the one who has a part in the first resurrection [**baptism into Christ**]; over these [**Christians**], the second death [**spiritual death**] has no power, but they [**Christians**] will be priests of God and of Christ [**ALL Christians are priests and royalty, cf. 1 Peter 2:9**] and will reign with Him for a thousand years [**until the end of time: Christ’s return**].”

The “thousand years” in this passage, as the bracketed notation indicates, is used to symbolize the time that remains relative to the end of time, that is, the balance of time before Christ brings the world to an end.  As the faithful, we are “priests of God and of Christ,” and we are “reigning with Him” – just as all saints have, now, precisely as the passage from Revelation tells us. In case we doubt this:

> **1 Peter 2:9**: "But [Christians] are A CHOSEN RACE, A royal PRIESTHOOD, A HOLY NATION, A PEOPLE FOR God’s OWN POSSESSION, so that you may proclaim the excellencies [Scripture] of Him [Christ] who has called you out of darkness into His marvelous light"

Comment: This "baptism into Christ" is your idea and not biblical.

Comment: @user48152 Thanks for that. I'm really not sure how else someone can read this: **Romans 6:4**: "Therefore we have been *buried with Him through baptism [water immersion] into death*, so that as Christ was raised from the dead through the glory of the Father, so we too might walk in newness of life."

Comment: This must be understood as a *type* of what will be. True believers will be raised in newness, spirit newness, (which is *not* only a deposit) at Jesus’ return. Now we have the deposit only, this is not the time of being born again. We are merely in the *process* of being born from above.

Comment: @user48152 In Christ, we have made a down payment. And, as long as we continue to make further payments, we can expect eternal life and if we die outside of Christ, there is eternal salvation. True, we "[have] the first fruits of the Spirit, [as] we ourselves groan within ourselves, waiting... the redemption of our body." So, we obviously do not possess at present, but we will when we enter the Presence of God. Obedience to God is absolutely paramount. We see examples of this throughout all of Scripture. If God tells us we must be "buried with Him through water immersion" then we must do that.